# Compile libssh for ESP32

Tags: libssh, esp32

I am trying to use the [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) library on the ESP32. When I compile the program, I get lots of errors.

The first error is "fatal error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory." I commented it out just to see if I could get past it, and it says it can't find bignum.

Any idea how to get libssh to work on a micro-controller like the ESP32?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your bigest problem is that you have no operating system.

linux on esp32 won't work because it has no MMU. 
maybe freertos has possibilities.

why would you need ssh on esp32. 
maybe an https webserver with basic authentication could serve your goals.